# new at programming, can't get my main window to open

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried comparing it to other programs I made and such, but so far I am not seeing any mistakes. A window should be showing up with 4 buttons on it.

I am including the code so if anyone figures out why my TK window won't open that will help a ton

```
""" dndcc.py a dungeon and dragon character creator
    created by Alex Deal
    includes several objects and lots of windows
"""
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import MessageBox

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.headerFont = ("Times New Roman", "16", "bold italic")

        self.title("dnd character creator")

        self.btnNew = Button(self, text= "Create New", command = self.makeNewFrame)
        self.btnNew.grid(row = 0)

        self.btnSave = Button(self, text= "Save Current", command = self.saveFile)
        self.btnSave.grid(row = 1)

        self.btnLoad = Button(self, text = "Load File", command = self.loadFile)
        self.btnLoad.grid(row = 2)

        self.btnPrint = Button(self, text = "Create Character Sheet", command = self.characterSheet)
        self.btnPrint.grid(row = 3)

def main():
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

ADDITIONAL QUESTIONS ABOUT TK:

So far TK is hard for me to grasp. I'm not having too many problems with other parts of my program, but I just don't get a lot of things about TK.

Specifically, is there a difference between self.mainloop() inside the app(TK) and app.mainloop() outside of it? I've seen both from my current teacher.

Also, how does making new frames work? I can't seem to find much information on creating a new frame (that is, changing the widgets on the current window without opening a new window).

Comment: Please only have one question per question. Ask the others in new questions, if they haven't been asked already.

Answer (score 2):

If this is your exact code, it needs two things:

1. It's `messagebox`, not `MessageBox`.
2. Functions bound to commands (`makeNewFrame`, etc.) must be defined, even if their bodies are just `pass` for now.

I fixed these issues and the main window opened up with the proper buttons.

If you want to change the widgets that appear in the window, use `grid_forget()` to remove unwanted widgets (you can delete the widgets as well if you wish), or simply reconfigure outdated widgets with `config`. [Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) has a lot of good information.

Comment: thanks a ton and sorry I'm sure these questions are very basic, I'm still trying to gather resources for when I don't know something but so far stackoverflow is the main one I use.

Comment: Happy to help. One very useful skill to learn is how to interpret tracebacks (error messages). That was 99% of how I solved your program's issue - I pasted it into an editor, ran it, fixed the problem described in the traceback, ran it again, and so on.